# trying to connect to localhost using mysql, php and apache on mac os mavericks

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, localhost

Im trying to connect to mysql locally using apache and php. I can connect to mysql using mysql workbench and i can use php with apache, but i can't connect to mysql using php.
When i try i get the following:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection refused in /Library/WebServer/Documents/login.php on line 25
```

This is the code:

```
mysql_connect($connection= mysql_connect("localhost", "RainyCats", "********");
```

I have also tried it with the root:

```
mysql_connect($connection= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "********");
```

The mysql preference pane in system preferences shows that the server is running, i have granted all privileges to RainyCats.

I have created the symbolic link to the mysql.sock from /private/var/mysql/mysql.sock to /tmp/mysql.sock
The my.cnf file is located in etc/my.cnf

I installed mysql using the dmg.

EDIT: I have php version: 5.4.24 and Apache: 2.2.26

Thank you,
Rainy

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Mountain Lion OS, it's probably a socket error behind this.
It seems that for local servers on Macos, you've got to specify what socket file your mysql-server is using, to your php code:

- So first, you will tell me "OK but where the hell is my socket file ?":

  ```
  $prompt> mysql -u myusername -p
  (enter the password here)

  mysql> show variables like '%socket%';

  +---------------+-----------------+
  | Variable_name | Value           |
  +---------------+-----------------+
  | socket        | /tmp/mysql.sock |
  +---------------+-----------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  ```
- Once you've got the path, use it in your php code:

  ```
  $username = 'myusername';
  $password = 'mypassword';
  $host = 'localhost:/tmp/mysql.sock';
  $database = 'mydatabase';

  #connect to the database or die
  $link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
  if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db ($database);
  ```

Thanks to Alvin, I found this solution on [his website](http://alvinalexander.com/mysql/mysql_connect-cant-connect-local-mysql-server-socket):

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the help, the situation has changed slightly: Mysql server instance will not start from system preferences, it just rotates then says stopped. i can't start it from terminal either, my php connects to mysql if i change the host to 127.0.0.1. The error i get when i try to connect through terminal is: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)